# OpenCV 2.2 Windows XP MinGW build crashes on namedWindow, imshow

Tags: windows, crash, opencv, mingw

I downloaded the latest OpenCV 2.2 sources for Windows and compiled on Windows XP using MinGW 4.4.1, with the help of CMake 2.8.

Everything went smoothly and compilation (mingw32-make) and installation (mingw32-make install) completed successfully.

However, when I compile some code containing namedWindow() and imshow() functions of highgui, it compiles but the program crashes. The following single line of code crashes:

namedWindow("img", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

The sample programs coming with OpenCV, displaying images, also crash.

Have anyone experienced the same problem, and do you have a solution?

I have also compiled and am using OpenCV 2.2 on linux (Ubuntu) without any problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there a reason that you would like to use OpenCV with MinGW and not Visual Studio? My OpenCV under Visual Studio works just fine.

Answer (score 4):

I've the same problem. I built OpenCV 2.2 under WindowsXP, using CMake, MSYS-make and mingw.

The sollution is explained here: [mingw32 SSE/SSE2 instabilities](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/583)

What I have done is the following:

1. Use CMake (2.8.4), specify target directory and run "Configure" for MSYS's make.
2. Type `Debug` at "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE".
3. Remove checkmark for "SSE2".
4. Run "Configure" again.
5. Run "Generate".
6. Run `make` at target directory.
7. Run `make install`.

This worked for me.