# Unhandled exception on OpenCV+VS2010

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I can build and execute the code below successfully :

```
 IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:\\hello.jpg");
 cvNamedWindow("myfirstwindow");
 cvShowImage("myfirstwindow", img);
```

But I got the unhandled exception when executed the code below:

```
    cv::Mat image= cv::imread("boldt.jpg");
    cv::namedWindow("Image");
    cv::imshow("Image",image);
```

although,I can build the code successfully.

I'm using opencv2.2 with VS2010 x86 version on windows 7 x86 version.
please help !

update: I tried it on winxp ,and it works fine...and it works fine with win7 on Release mode only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using OpenCV 2.3.1 and when I run it in Release mode (linked to a release highgui lib), everything is fine.
When I switch to Debug mode (still linked to a release highgui lib), it crashes.
Linking to a debug highgui lib helped.

Maybe you have the same problem...

Comment: Yeah, we got the same problem.I update to OpenCV2.3.1 and still crash on Debug mode, but works fine on Release mode.

Comment: Seperate the debug and release .libs for your project in vc10 .. fixed my problem

Answer (score 5):

**It might be** the problem where people don't realize that when VStudio runs your application it tries to find it's resources in the same directory as the compiled executable and **not** in the folder where the source files are.

Your first code works because you are loading the image passing the FULL PATH to the file!

That's why is so important to check the success of functions when you are coding:

```
try 
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("boldt.jpg");

    if (!image.data) 
        printf("!!! No data !!!");
} 
catch(std::exception e) 
{
    printf("Exception: [%s]\n", e.what());
}
```

This sort of programming practice will save you a lot of time.

**EDIT**:

Well, if the crash is still happening it means that it could be either `cv::namedWindow()` or `cv::imshow()` fault, and [my money is on `cv::namedWindow()`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=namedWindow).

Other users reported a similar behavior on Windows:

[OpenCV 2.2 Windows XP MinGW build crashes on namedWindow, imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4609069/176769)

[Open CV crashes under WIN7 when opening NamedWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4726041/176769)

[namedWindow() causes crash in opencv 2.3.1? (Eclipse+MinGW on XP, C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7996032/176769)

**It seems that [to solve the problem you need to disable SSE](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/583) optimizations.**

Comment: thanks for your answer..But I still got the same problem after changed to FULL PATH . And the exception code above didnt work either and got the same unhandled exception error when executed the code.

Comment: Updated answer! this is probably a [known bug of OpenCV on Windows](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/583).

Comment: thanks for your reply..the crash still occur after I update to 2.3.1 and the SSE method didn't work for me..Anyway, it works fine on Release mode, seems a good alternative solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked the output of the imread() function?

```
if(image.empty())
{
        cout << "where's my image?" << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer..the unhandle exceptions error occur with a single line :" cv::Mat image= cv::imread("1.jpg");"..I think the imread function cannot be executed in my VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem as have been described.

It turns out that the problem very much lies with the settings of the linker!

I found the answer in another thread:
[OpenCV 2.3 and Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666563/opencv-2-3-and-visual-studio-2010)

Here it is:

"Properties of your project (right click on it)

- C/C++
- - General
- - - include directory add the < your directory >\OpenCV2.3\include\opencv2, < your directory >\OpenCV2.3\include\opencv and < your directory >\OpenCV2.3\include
- Linker
- - General
- - - List item
- - Input
- - - Add all the libs like opencv_core230d.lib opencv_highgui230d.lib and so on..."

Once I've done the above, I can run imshow and imread + all other cpp functions seamlessly! The author who asked the question probably has already solved it. but just in case there are other people who are led here looking for the same solution!

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the "C:\OpenCV2.4.3\build\x86\vc10\bin" added to the path. NOT(!) the "C:\OpenCV2.4.3\build\x86\vc9\bin". This may cause the problem.

For the use of opencv with visual studio there are two realy good docs:

[Viual Studio 2010 and OpenCV-2-4-x](http://www.anlak.com/using-opencv-2-4-x-with-visual-studio-2010-tutorial/)

[The official OpenCv-Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/opencv_tutorials.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Check in the folders that generates the compilation, because in one of them is the .exe compiled, and it is possible that the image that you want to open is not there. In my case the .exe (in the Debuge mode) was in C:\Users\Name\source\repos\HolaMundox\x64\Debug, and not were I create my .cpp that was on C:\Users\Name\source\repos\HolaMundox. Something similar will apply with the Release mode. 
Other thing is that you must check well the extension of the image, if it is .jpg, .jpeg, .bmp, and so on... one error that I had was that I put the extención .jpg and it was .jpeg.