# Can't access mat's data after using copyTo command

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

`Src` & `dst` are 3x3 cv::Mat with type `32FC1`.

After copy data,

```
Src.col(0).copyTo(dst.col(2));
Src.col(1).copyTo(dst.col(0));
Src.col(2).copyTo(dst.col(1));
```

access `dst` data like `dst.at<double>(1,1)` return error.

`Unhandled exception at 0x7530812f in matrix.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x002fedc8..`

Please tell me the reason.

Comment: Is it built in Debug mode? If so have you included debug `highgui`?

Comment: You mean this `<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>`. I already included.

Comment: yeah but is it built in debug or release mode?

Comment: built in debug mode.

Comment: There seems to be people having similar issues here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164932/unhandled-exception-on-opencvvs2010 you may need to link against a debug version of hihgui

Comment: I included both `highgui.lib` & `opencv_highgui240d.lib`. I think it be ok when run in Debug mode.

Comment: please only use ***d.lib in debug mode. mixing debug and release libs will lead exactly to those problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`32FC1` is single precision, i.e. `dst.at<float>(1,1)`! So either use that or change the type to `64FC1`.

Comment: jikes, we all missed the obvious ;)